# How to change the order on how numbers are entered into a UITextField or UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield, uilabel

How can I enter numbers into a `UILabel` or `UITextField` in a way that they always flow to the right instead of the left as they are entered? In other words if I type one, two, thee I want them to be displayed as 321 instead of the traditional way 123.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: u need to write the case statement ?

Comment: I seriously don't know understand the down-votes sometimes. @Whoever down-voted this question - Can you please explain why the down-vote so I know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Implementing a method from the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol would allow you to do so.

> `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`
>
> Asks the
>   delegate if the specified text should be changed.
>
> Discussion: The text field calls this method whenever the user types a
>   new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

For the typing you'd need something along the lines of:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textField text]];
    if ( [string length] > 0 ) {
        // insert new characters at the beginning
        [str insertString:string atIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        // i'm leaving the implementation of the deletion code to you

    }

    [textField setText:str];

}
```

Don't forget to set the UITextField's delegate to the class implementing this function.

Note that this implementation is just a sample, it would fail if the user pastes a string with more than 1 character (you'd have to reverse the string and then insert it to the beginning of the mutable string in the example).

Comment: Cool, this should work, I will give it a try and let you know (will come back and accept answer).  Thanks a lot

Comment: I forgot the return value, as Lapinou noted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you for the sample code Alexander!

But, this shouldn't work correctly. You have to return YES or NO like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textField text]];
    if ( [string length] > 0 ) {

        // insert new characters at the beginning
        [str insertString:string atIndex:0];
        [textField setText:str];

        return NO;
    }
    else {
        // i'm leaving the implementation of the deletion code to you
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lapinou, your code worked fine, thank you for catching what Alexander missed otherwise I wouldn't figure it out, I appreciate it. I marked Alexander's as the answer since he was the first one and he actually provided 90% of the code. thanks a lot.